# Who was lady Comstock?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

During the game from the recordings on the voxaphones made by lady Comstock, she repeatedly tells that

> She is a sinner that have done many bad things, and that she doesn't deserve the forgiveness that the prophet gave her.

The question is

> What did she do before she met Comstock, and what are her sins?

Answer (score 7):

There's not much backstory on Lady Comstock in the game proper.  There's but [one Voxophone](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Unconditional) that goes into any detail:

> To those who loved me, I was the most generous of souls. There was no pain I would deny them. No betrayal I would not gladly give. And when I had scorched the hearts of all who loved me, the Prophet said, "There is nothing you can do for which I will not forgive you, for God has granted me sight, and through His eyes, even you are loved."

When I heard this, I interpret it as:

> Lady Comstock was beautiful and had many suitors, ("those who loved me") and she was particularly abusive to them ("no pain I would deny them[,] no betrayal I would not gladly give").  It's possible she's also referring to her family, though.

This is still relatively vague, but:

> In order for this to be something so terrible that it would require the level of forgiveness she references, I assume she must have been unfaithful towards her lovers.  She seems willing to forgive [quite a few serious transgressions](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Beyond_Redemption) the Prophet does, including mass murder.

Comment: I took it to mean she had an even more unsavory past, like an assassin.  But that would probably be too cool.